# Reading from stdin using fgets()

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, malloc, fgets

I'm new to C programming and I'm currently trying to read a line from stdin using fgets(), but I'm having trouble with memory allocation since I'm using a char* to point to the string I want to read. When I execute the file it reports a segmentation fault.

This is the function I'm using:

```
char *read_line(char *line){
    printf("%s",PROMPT);
    line = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*500);
    fgets(line,sizeof(line),stdin);
    printf("%s","pasa el fgets");
    return line;
}
```

And my main:

```
void main(){
    char line0;
    char *line=&line0;
    while(read_line(line)){
        execute_line(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: `char line0; char *line=&line0;` Now `line` points to a `char` buffer of length 1. If your line is more than 1 byte in length, you'll overrun the buffer. Instead of just jamming code in until it compiles, try to actually *understand* what it is doing. I'd recommend a C tutorial, book, or course.

Comment: So many errors in so few lines of code ;-)

Comment: `sizeof(line)` is the size of a pointer, not the size of the allocate memory.

Comment: 1) `fgets(line,sizeof(line),stdin);` --> `fgets(line, 500, stdin);` 2) `while(read_line(line)){` --> `while(line = read_line(line)){` //need free(line); and break loop

Comment: @JonathonReinhart so you suggest a malloc there?

Answer (score 2):

The main mistake is to pass the pointer `line` to the function `read_line` (by value) and try to modify it in that function.

`read_line` allocates the memory and actually creates the pointer value. So it should be able to change the value of `line` in `main`:

```
char *read_line(char **line){
    ...
    *line = malloc(500);
    fgets(*line, 500, stdin);
    ...
    return *line;
}

int main(void) {
    char *line;
    while(read_line(&line)){
        ...
    }

}
```

Or, you use the return value of `read_line` in order to modify `main`'s `line`. In that case you don't need the parameter at all:

```
char *read_line(void) {
    char *line;
    ...
    line = malloc(500);
    fgets(line, 500, stdin);
    ... 
    return line;
}

int main(void) {
    char *line;
    while(line = read_line()){
        ...
    }
}
```

Additional errors (pointed out by Jonathon Reinhart) and remarks:

1. `sizeof` does not "work" for pointers (array decayed to pointers).
2. You `malloc` many strings `line` but you do not `free` them.
3. `sizeof(char)` is always 1.
4. Some people (me too) think that casting the result of `malloc` should be avoided.