# Can't understand this error while freeing memory in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, free, pass-by-value

I don't understand why I m am getting a segmentation fault inside the free_memory function. Here is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void allocate_memory (char **cells)
{
    int i;

    cells = (char **) malloc(9 * sizeof(char *));
    if (cells == NULL)
    {
        perror("Couldn't allocate memory");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        cells[i] = (char *) malloc(9 * sizeof(char));
        if (cells[i] == NULL)
        {
            perror("Couldn't allocate memory");
            exit(1);
        }

        memset(cells[i], 1, 9);
    }
}

void free_memory (char **cells)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        free(cells[i]);
    }

    free(cells);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char **cells = NULL;

    allocate_memory(cells);
    printf("Allocated\n");
    free_memory(cells);

    return 0;
}
```

The debugger shows this message about the error:

```
Process 1433 launched: '/Users/Jaime/Documents/workspaceC/PruebasC/PruebasC/sk' (x86_64)
Allocated
Process 1433 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x1058a, 0x0000000100000e95 sk`free_memory + 37, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x0000000100000e95 sk`free_memory + 37
sk`free_memory:
->  0x100000e95 <+37>: movq   (%rcx,%rax,8), %rdi
    0x100000e99 <+41>: callq  0x100000f20               ; symbol stub for: free
    0x100000e9e <+46>: movl   -0xc(%rbp), %eax
    0x100000ea1 <+49>: addl   $0x1, %eax
```

I hope anyone can help me, I don't get why I am accessing a bad pointer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading from stdin using fgets()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40412010/reading-from-stdin-using-fgets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not modifying your `main`'s `cells` in `allocate_memory`. You are modifying a copy.

If you want to modify a pointer in a function, you have to pass a pointer-to-pointer to the function:

```
...

void allocate_memory (char ***cells)
{
    int i;

    *cells = (char **) malloc(9 * sizeof(char *));
    if (*cells == NULL)
    {
        perror("Couldn't allocate memory");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        (*cells)[i] = (char *) malloc(9 * sizeof(char));
        if ((*cells)[i] == NULL)
        {
            perror("Couldn't allocate memory");
            exit(1);
        }

        memset((*cells)[i], 1, 9);
    }
}

...    

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char **cells = NULL;

    allocate_memory(&cells);

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C uses pass-by-value for function argument passing. In case you want to allocate memory to `cells` itself, you need to either

- pass a pointer to it, or
- return the newly allocated pointer and store it back into the `cells` in `main()`.

  Otherwise, the `cells` in the `allocate_memory()` function is local to that any any change made to `cells` will be lost once you return from that function.

As a result, inside `free_memory()` function, the access `cells[i]` is invalid, as `cells` does not point to any valid memory, at all. Attempt to access invalid memory invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 0):

The allocation function doesn't return a newly allocated block.
 allocate_memory(cells);

The external effect is as if cells was not set by the function (previously set to NULL)